# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField fields to display from its queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a ModelForm with a ModelMultipleChoiceField.

```
users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
  widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'chzn-select'}),
   queryset = User.objects.filter(...))
```

My list is displayed by username, as the default `repr` method of the model.

I want to display the `first_name` and the `last_name` without overloading the `repr` method, because I need username in other cases.

I wouldn't like to get the `values_list('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')`, because later I don't get a model list on `save()` but tuples.

Is there any setting/hack for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter the object representation by overriding label_from_instance, which is part of the ModelChoiceField class that ModelMultipleChoiceField inherits.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you trying to add jquery-chosen selects?
There's django app django-chosen at https://github.com/theatlantic/django-chosen
There's available fields:
- ChosenChoiceField
- ChosenModelChoiceField
- ChosenMultipleChoiceField
- **ChosenModelMultipleChoiceField**